# flutter routes causing error - could not navigate between 2 pages

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, flutter-dependencies

I am building a small application in flutter where I am getting following error.

[image]

Can some one help me to fix this out and tell me what is the actual reason?

I have used routes to navigate between application. It was working fine firstly but then, I used named routes to navigate between different pages of flutter application.
And then the error came.

I am posting the code and complete project structure so, it becomes easy to understand what's going on.

I just want to resolve this error.

**This is home page code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_practice/pages/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_practice/pages/routes.dart';
import 'package:flutter_practice/pages/routes.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int a = 30;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Catalog App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Welcome to flutter bhai $a"),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      routes: {
        MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),
        MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => loginPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**This is Login page code ( Second page)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_practice/pages/routes.dart';

class loginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "assets/images/login_image.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              child: Text("Hi, I am in the box"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 32.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter User Name",
                      labelText: "User Name",
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Password",
                      labelText: "Password",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute); 
                },
                child: Text("login"),
                style: TextButton.styleFrom()),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

**This is the third page (where I defined routes seperately**

```
class MyRoutes {
  static String loginRoute = "/login";
  static String homeRoute = "/home";
}
```

What I want is that when I push the button then on onPressed() method the route should be called correctly.

I would love to listen to your input and what do you think of it.

Regards,
Ali

Comment: Hi, I found a solution so thought to update it.

Comment: I have just commented down the code of routes:{} in the home page and when I rebuilt it it again started to fun and the routing function performed well with the named routes. I think when I defined the NamedRoutes class in the new file then the previous routes:{} have been overridden and that's why compiler was confused that which one ro consider.